# Would there be a better way of doing this?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

```cs
post.Min.ToString("0.00").Replace(",", ".").Replace(".00", string.Empty)
```

`post.Min` is a double such as `12,34` or `12,00`. Expected output is `12.34` or `12`.

I basically want to replace the comma by a point, and cut the `.00` part if any.

I am asking because I couldn't find anything, or because I don't exactly know what to search. This has an high change of being a duplicate, I simply can't find it. Please let me know.

Comment: That's fine, a slightly more orthodox method is using a `ToString` overload

Comment: @JeremyThompson Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: What is input and what is an expected output? Update your question with sample input and output. I believe two `Replace()` might be redundant just want to confirm it by seeing sample input and output

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Input is a double such as ``12,34`` or ``12,00``. Expected output is ``12.34`` or ``12``. Updated, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to replicate what CultureInfo does. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: @EricJ. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I think you'll find with experience that reinventing the wheel isn't the simplest way, but a sign that it's worth investing a little time in better understanding that wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would appear to be to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, and I reject the suggestion that this is any more complicated than using a series of replaces as you demonstrated in your question.

```
post.Min.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`#` is the digit placeholder, described as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) like this:

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FGQUVR26198)

---

If you use this in a lot of places, and that's why you want to keep it simple, you could make an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToHappyString(this double value)
    {
        return value.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

And then you just have to call `.ToHappyString()` wherever you use it. For example, `post.Min.ToHappyString()`

Comment: If you are fine with `12.234` formatted as `12.234` (not `12.23`) than you can also simplify that by removing format string altogether `post.Min.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`... To simplify even more `using static System.Globalization.CultureInfo` and `post.Min.ToString(InvariantCulture)`...

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I see. Thanks a lot for your time and your well redacted answer. Thanks to @AlexeiLevenkov as well for your precisions!

Comment: It is worth noting, that this gives different result than the original code for numbers like 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ToString("0.##")`.

like,

```
// Considered german culture; May be this is your current culture
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de"); 
double number1 = Double.Parse("12,34", culture);
double number2 = Double.Parse("12,00", culture);

Console.WriteLine(number1.ToString("0.##"));
Console.WriteLine(number2.ToString("0.##"));
```

Output:

```
12.34
12
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2tYCn)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this do seem to output ``12,45``, not ``12.45``.

Comment: ``post.Min.ToString("0.##")`` still do output ``12,45``, with a comma and not a dot.

Comment: @madreflection I totally agree my first code was not tested. Now I tried on *.net fiddle.* Also added POC to support my answer

Comment: That may be, but the *setup* part of your answer is unnecessarily complicated now. Just assign values as literals. No need to parse them. The question doesn't have to do with parsing, so that's pointless noise. Version 1 was fine with `double` literals. But even now, you're not dealing with the culture in the output. OP is in `fr-FR`. Test it with that as the current culture and you'll see what they get.

Comment: @madreflection, Yes if OP is in `fr-FR` culture then no need to parse string to double. I did it to parse given no in `de` format. If we set it as a current culture then John's solution is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [`ToString overloads article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) on MSDN about examples of the `N` format. This is also covered in the [`Standard Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) article.

Relevant examples:

```
//       Formatting of 1054.32179:
//          N:                     1,054.32 
//          N0:                    1,054 
//          N1:                    1,054.3 
//          N2:                    1,054.32 
//          N3:                    1,054.322
```

For the dot instead of comma to do it properly, in combination with `N0` use:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Comment: "to do it properly" - what you suggesting is questionable as you may endup with `1.234.56`... I'd just stick with `InvariantCulture` like `(1.00).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this seem a bit too much, my main goal is to try keeping it as simple as possible. Wouldn't it be possible in a different way? Thank you.

Comment: @Laiteux yes - like buggy solution you have in the question giving potentially two dots... Actually moving to place that *properly* use "." as decimal separator would solve it for you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks and good pick up (as usual). OP I intended you would use `N0` and the dot with the thread culture.

Answer (score 0):

`double.ToString("0.##")` to consider decimal places only if not .00 and you can create your own Number Format without using Culture:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

post.Min.ToString("0.##", nfi);
```